# pthreads not working correctly

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, pthreads

I have the following code which was simplified to show only the relevant part.

My problem is that on one machine it shows correctly the thread number and all the other values but when I run it on other machines it shows the same values for all the threads created.

I compile it with -lpthread, I even tried to compile it statically but same results.

Why does it work correctly on one machine and on others not? Is it some coding mistake or do I have to change libraries upon compilation? 
I am stuck. Thanks!

```
    pthread_mutex_t word_list;
    struct words_list {
        char myword[20];
        struct words_list * next;
    };
    struct arg_struct {
        char *myword;
        int t;
    };
    char myword[20];
    struct words_list * first_word = NULL;
            //the loading data into struct code is missing from here
    struct words_list * curr_word = first_word;
    pthread_mutex_init(&word_list,NULL);        
    int ex = 0;
    while(curr_word != NULL)
    {
        struct arg_struct args;
        int ret = -1;
        for(i = 0 ; i < max_thread; i++)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&word_list);
            strncpy(myword,curr_word->myword,sizeof(myword) - 1);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&word_list);
            args.myword = myword;
            args.t = i;

            //start threads
            if(pthread_create(&thread_id[i],NULL,&do_repl,&args) != 0)
            {
                i--;
                fprintf(stderr,RED "\nError in creating thread\n" NONE);
            }
            else
            {
                pthread_mutex_lock(&word_list);
                if(curr_word->next == NULL)
                    ex = 1;
                else
                    curr_word = curr_word->next;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&word_list);
            }
        }//end threads creating

        for(i = 0 ; i < max_thread; i++)
        {
            void *join_result;
            if(pthread_join(thread_id[i],&join_result) != 0)
                fprintf(stderr,RED "\nError in joining thread\n" NONE);
            else
            {
                ret = *(int *)join_result;
                free(join_result);
                if((ret == 1)
                {
                    ex = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }//end threads joining
        if (ex == 1)
            break;
    }//end while






    void* do_repl(void *arguments)
    {
        int *res = malloc(sizeof(int));
        struct arg_struct *args = arguments;
        char *word = args->word;
        int t = args->t;
        fprintf(stderr,"(%d) word: %s\n",t,word);
        *res = 0;
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: have you defined `first_word` anywhere?

Comment: of course, but I guess I deleted by mistake when I was cleaning the code for posting. I will update the post

Comment: The question title seems a little overt.

Comment: Your question title is rather presumptuous.  It is more likely that pthreads works correctly but your code is not working as you wanted than that pthreads does not work correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your have multiple issues in this code, starting with your arg structure. The same logical arg structure is being shared by *all* your threads, introducing among other things, a severe race-condition:

```
struct arg_struct args; // << == Note. Local variable.
int ret = -1;
for(i = 0 ; i < max_thread; i++)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&word_list);
    strncpy(myword,curr_word->myword,sizeof(myword) - 1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&word_list);
    args.myword = myword;
    args.t = i;

    //start threads NOTE: args passed by address.
    if(pthread_create(&thread_id[i],NULL,&do_repl,&args) != 0)
    {
        i--;
        fprintf(stderr,RED "\nError in creating thread\n" NONE);
    }

    // rest of code...
}
```

Now think for a moment what happens when that thread is launched. if your for-loop launches *multiple* threads before *some* of them have a chance to *access* that arg-stuct and pull out their specific thread-info, then those threads will be accessing the *last* data your saved in it, which would be the last iteration of the loop (if you're really unlucky, you may catch it mid-update, but I'm not diving into that level of detail; the point should be obvious).

I suggest you dynamically allocate the thread arguments structure, and have the thread destroy it when finished. As a *highly advised alternative* (and commonly done) use *that* as your return value through `pthread_join` and then let `main()` destroy it after extracting the thread-finish data.

Secondly, your args struct is using a pointer for `myword` which is set to the *same buffer* for every thread (the `char myword[20]` local variable). Therefore, even if you "fix" your argument structure to be dynamic you *still* have all your threads using the *same buffer*.

**Solution**

Dynamically allocate each threads argument structure. Within that, have a *local* copy of the word being processed. Likewise, store the return code for the thread the args will be passed to there as well (saves you the trouble of having to allocate one in the thread and free it in `main()`).

```
// thread arguments.
struct arg_struct
{
    char myword[20];
    int ret;
    int t;
};
```

In your thread startup loop:

```
while(curr_word != NULL)
{
    int ret = -1;
    for(i = 0 ; i < max_thread; i++)
    {
        // allocate a new  argument struct for the new thread
        struct arg_struct *args = calloc(1, sizeof(*args));
        args->t = i;

        // this lock is pointless, btw.
        pthread_mutex_lock(&word_list);
        strcpy(args->myword, cur_word->myword); //note: assumes no overrun.
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&word_list);

        //start threads
        if(pthread_create(&thread_id[i],NULL, &do_repl, args) != 0)
        {
            i--;
            fprintf(stderr,RED "\nError in creating thread\n" NONE);
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&word_list);
            if(curr_word->next == NULL)
                ex = 1;
            else
                curr_word = curr_word->next;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&word_list);
        }
    }//end threads creating

    for(i = 0 ; i < max_thread; i++)
    {
        void *join_result = NULL;
        if(pthread_join(thread_id[i], &join_result) != 0)
            fprintf(stderr,RED "\nError in joining thread\n" NONE);
        else
        {
            ret = ((struct arg_struct*)join_result)->ret;
            free(join_result);
            if((ret == 1)
            {
                ex = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }//end threads joining

    if (ex == 1)
        break;
}//end while
```

And in the thread proc, simply do this:

```
void* do_repl(void *arguments)
{
    struct arg_struct *args = arguments;
    fprintf(stderr,"(%d) word: %s\n", args->t, args->word);
    args->ret = 0;
    return args;
}
```

Sorry for any typos I may have left, but I hope you get the point.

---

**EDIT** The OP requested a simple thread example that launches threads with custom argument blocks. The following does just that as well as exposes the actual linked list directly to the thread crew. The threads all share a common pointer (by address, so pointer to pointer) that initially points to the list head, and is protected with a mutex (which the threads also share). All threads run until they detect the list is empty, at which point they exit. This means you could load a list significantly larger list than your pool (I chose a pool of 5, with a list of 20, but you can have *many* more entries in your list than that).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>


typedef struct node
{
    char myword[20];
    struct node *next;
} node;

// thread arguments.
typedef struct arg_struct
{
    pthread_mutex_t *mtx;
    node **pp;
    int ret;
    int t;
} arg_struct;


// thread procedure. doesn't do much
void* do_repl(void *arguments)
{
    arg_struct *args = arguments;

    while (1)
    {
        // lock, get, and unlock
        pthread_mutex_lock(args->mtx);
        node *p = *args->pp;
        if (p)
        {
            *args->pp = p->next;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(args->mtx);

            // print the node we just got from the list.
            fprintf(stderr,"(%d) word: %s\n", args->t, p->myword);
        }
        else
        {
            // no more entries in list. break
            break;
        }
    };

    // make sure this is released
    pthread_mutex_unlock(args->mtx);

    args->ret = 0;
    return args;
}

// main entrypoint.
int main()
{
    // very simple. we use a fixed number of threads and list nodes.
    static const int n_threads = 5;

    // build a simple forward-only linked list. will have 4x the
    //  number of threads in our crew.
    node *list = NULL;
    node **next = &list;
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0;i<n_threads*4;++i)
    {
        node *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
        sprintf(p->myword, "String-%d", i+1);
        *next = p;
        next = &(p->next);
    }
    *next = NULL;


    // declare a mutex and thread pool for hitting all the elements
    //  in the linked list.
    pthread_mutex_t mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_t threads[n_threads];

    // lock the mutex before creating the thread pool.
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);

    i = 0;
    node *shared = list;
    for (int i=0; i<n_threads; ++i)
    {
        // setup some thread arguments.
        arg_struct *args = calloc(1, sizeof(*args));
        args->mtx = &mtx;
        args->pp = &shared;
        args->t = i+1;

        // launch the thread.
        pthread_create(threads + i, NULL, do_repl, args);
    }

    // now unlatch the mutex and wait for the threads to finish.
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    for (i=0;i<n_threads;++i)
    {
        void *pv = NULL;
        pthread_join(threads[i], &pv);

        arg_struct *args = pv;
        fprintf(stderr,"Thread %d finished\n", args->t);
        free(args);
    }

    // cleanup the linked list.
    while (list != NULL)
    {
        node *p = list;
        list = list->next;
        free(p);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output** (varies by system and run-instance)

```
(2) word: String-2
(1) word: String-1
(3) word: String-3
(4) word: String-4
(5) word: String-5
(2) word: String-6
(1) word: String-7
(3) word: String-8
(4) word: String-9
(5) word: String-10
(2) word: String-11
(1) word: String-12
(3) word: String-13
(4) word: String-14
(2) word: String-16
(1) word: String-17
(5) word: String-15
(3) word: String-18
(4) word: String-19
(2) word: String-20
Thread 1 finished
Thread 2 finished
Thread 3 finished
Thread 4 finished
Thread 5 finished
```

Note the thread id reporting each string. This proves each thread is consuming *multiple* entries on the list, but each is going to only one thread. The shared pointer in the arguments block ensures this (as well as the obvious mutex protection).

Comment: Your answer is simply amazing but my implementation sucks. I tried it but after I modified with struct arg_struct *args = calloc(1, sizeof(*args)); it doesn't get data from the other structure anymore and it crashes. I followed step by step your guide but I guess I did something wrong or maybe the script doesn't like the new struct with calloc. dunno :(

Comment: @SamReina Doesn't get data from *what* other structure anymore? You mean copying the data out of the linked list you're processing and into each thread's arg struct? I'm not really privy to your data structure layout, so its hard to know for sure what you mean. Did you want the `args` for each thread to reference the strings *in* your linked list directly ? That is certainly doable, especially now that each thread has its own args blob.

Comment: @SamReina Also, as I look at it, I think your thread-start loop is missing a `break` condition if the number of words in your list is less than your max thread pool size. That would obviously cause severe problems. Further, if the list of strings is *larger* than `max_thread` only `max_thread` strings will be processed. I'm fairly sure thats not what you want either.

Comment: that break condition is in the original code, I just skipped it in this post, but thanks for the tip. It doesn't get cur_word->myword, it just shows null instead of the word. And I don't know why, maybe I altered the code while I was modifying it based on your solution

Comment: besides that it shows 0 for the crt thread (in void do_repl) for every thread. so it doesn't count anymore. if I remove the calloc and leave the arg_struct like it was before it shows, so I guess it's related to calloc

Comment: @SamReina I'll try and put together a stand-alone sample. I'm assuming your linked list is pretty generic. Its no problem. Give me a few minutes and I'll add the sample as an addendum to the original answer.

Comment: thank you so much! and one more question: if I use the arg struct with calloc does it mean all records will be held in memory or the contents of the struct will be destroyed after each thread completion? It would be great to be something volatile, not to be held into memory until program exits. Sorry for so many n00b questions :P

Comment: @SamReina `calloc` is just a vector-type allocator that allocates N items of size M, zero-filling the memory in doing so. Think of it like a `malloc()` that does the math for your and zero-fills as a bonus. The main thread still needs to free the memory. The thread proc should NOT in the sample I posted above. Still working on a thread-only sample to update. Almost done.

Comment: @SamReina there you go. that should run stand-alone. And note it is different than the prior sample in a number of ways, most notable the string pointers in the arguments structures. they are not copies. Rather they are pointers to the *live* data in the linked list. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks so much WhozCraig for your effort! your example works like charm. I will try to implement it in my current program. Hope I will succeed. I accepted your answer.